# Wordpress menu not working after update

Tags: wordpress, menu, angularjs

I purchased the Angular theme for wordpress some months ago for a portfolio site to show off my front-end web dev work (Too lazy to create my own).

I went to update the site last night and noticed that the menu had stopped functioning. If I click on a menu item the URL will change to the URL of the link but the page will remain on the current page and not display the content of the new URL.

My website is http://www.decodedcreative.com.
Does anyone have any ideas or things that I could try to resolve the problem?
I have switched the theme to the twentytwelve theme and the menu then works as expected and have also tried re downloading the entire Angular theme in case I'd corrupted a file.

Any ideas?

Thanks

P.S - I've also tried restarting Apache on my server but to no avail. This question is also asked on the support forum for the theme.

Answer (score 0):

When you are viewing the list of pages in Wordpress, try using the "Quick edit" to edit the page Slug.  Even though I had updated the permalink when you use the "Edit" link, it didn't actually update the slug.  Updating the slug will fix it.